# Redux Saga- return the result to callee function instead of dispatching new action

Tags: reactjs, redux, yield, redux-saga

I am moving my react project to redux & redux-saga. Initially, I was calling an async method to get large data sets and then I was setting it in my local state, something like this:

```
// Component.jsx
componentDidMount() {
   const dataPromise = this.getTableData()
   const data = await dataPromise
   this.setState({ data })
}

getTableData = async() => {
   const response = await APIUtils.getTableData()
   let data = null
   if (response && response.code === "200") {
      data = response.data
   }
   return data
}
```

Now with redux, I am changing it like this

```
// Component.jsx
componentDidMount() {
  const data = this.props.getTableData() // how to get data here?
  this.setState({ data })
}

// ActionCreator.js
function getTableData() {
   return {
     type: "GET_TABLE_DATA"
   }
}

// saga.js
function *getTableData() {
   try {
        const response = yield call(APIUtils.getTableData)
        ...
        // here I want to send this response.data to my comp without calling store action as the dataset is large and it is read-only.

    } catch (err) {
        yield put(showError(false))
    }
}

export default function* root() {
  yield all([
    takeLatest("GET_TABLE_DATA", getTableData)
  ])
}
```

I am new to redux-saga, anyone tell me what is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dispatch an action that will update your store. Then you connect your component to the store and get data from the store.

Comment: The whole idea is I don't want to keep this data in the store because the data set is large and it is not changing or used anywhere else.

Comment: But without using a store, data will be stored in your component anyway. And if you don't want to have it in the store all the time you can dispatch an action to remove it from the store when your component gets unmounted.

Comment: Yeah, basically I want to keep the data in the component state only. Can I avoid storing the data in the store and the removal on component unmount by directly passing the response data to the instance where it is called? Should I use a callback method in the dispatched action?

Comment: If you don't want to use store then you don't need sagas and actions just use your previous approach and call api directly from your component.

Comment: well said, use saga to update store if you want to save data in store.... if you want to store data in local class state or variable , no need to use saga just fetch inside component.